# Hyperlink handle in asp.net does not work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

tell me what i'm doing wrong?

There is some code:

```
<td><a data-value="<%# Eval("godzina") %>" runat="server" onserverclick="godziny_Click" class="godziny" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><%# Eval("godzina") %></a></td>
```

And I want it handle to asp.net so I gonna use method onclickserver but It is not working.

There is some c# code:

```
protected void godziny_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var godzina = TimeSpan.Parse(hidden2.Value);
        var query = from h in bazaDC.seanses
                    where h.godzina == godzina
                    select h;

        foreach(var a in query)
        {
            id_seansu = a.id_seansu;
        }
    }
```

I would like to do that code when I click that hyperlink but when I went to that page I see error in browser something like Error with parser, exactly in that line with html code. Something like that because I have browser in my first language.

Comment: Try data-value='<%# Eval("godzina") %>'   The databinder could be getting confused because the double quotes in the Eval could end up treated as string terminators by mistake.

Comment: Weee! It's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<a data-value='<%# Eval("godzina") %>'
```

there should be single quotes instead of double